# Is there a way to grant permissions to edit just one type of page layout (for just one object)?

Tags: administration, admin, user-admin

I want to be able to give a "Super User" (non admin) the ability to edit only Knowledge layouts. I don't want them to be able to edit Account layouts, for example. I also don't want to restrict access to other objects or records. I just want to restrict the ability to edit Layouts to only one object. (Knowledge) Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Editing layouts is a broad permission. Both "View Setup and Configuration" and "Customize Application" profile permission are reqy to change all PAGE LAYOUTs.

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LjSpAAK